# How do I open an HTML file from my Mac OSX home directory in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, osx-elcapitan

I want to open an HTML file that I am working on in Google Chrome. The file is located under my home directory:

```
/Users/samfredland/
```

When I select File/Open File... from the Google Chrome menu, my options include Documents, Downloads, Applications, etc., but there appears to be no way to navigate to /Users/samfredland and open a file located under that directory.

Can this be done? I am running El Capitan.

Comment: The dialog you're describing is a standard Mac OS X file dialog. There is absolutely nothing (besides, possibly, your own lack of experience with the OS) preventing you from using it to navigate to your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to add my home directory to the Finder sidebar. Now I can open files from it from any application.